# How can I get/use the map

Tags: apex

I have two inputfields at my visual force page to insert the `B_value_per_Month` and the `B_Birthdate`, after the calucaltion you will get the `B_result`.
For the calculation I need the time between the birthdate and the day of today, so far so good, but for each year (e.g. 3 years = 0.6) it's an other factor.

In my method `PageReference B_Calc_click()` I run the method `getB_runtime()`, but how can I put the the `B_runtime` into the method `get_B_runtime_facor()`?

```
public void getB_runtime_factor() {
    B_runtime_factor_Map = new Map <Double, Double>();
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(0, 1.000);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(1, 0.800);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(2, 0.700);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(3, 0.600);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(4, 0.500);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(5, 0.400);
    ......
}

public PageReference B_CALC_click() {
    B_runtime = Date.Today().daysBetween(B_Birthdate) / 365;
    getB_runtime_factor();      
    B_Result = B_Value_per_Month * 12 * B_runtime_factor;       
    return new PageReference('/apex/Parameter_info');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin's answer is correct, but I would refactor this to use static initialization to avoid having to call a method to initialize the map:

```
public Map<Double, Double> B_runtime_factor = new Map<Double, Double> {
    0 => 1.000, 
    1 => .800, 
    2 => .700, 
    ...
};

public PageReference B_CALC_click() {
    B_runtime = Date.Today().daysBetween(B_Birthdate) / 365;
    B_Result = B_Value_per_Month * 12 * B_runtime_factor.get(B_runtime);       
    return new PageReference('/apex/Parameter_info');  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understand well your question.

First, I think there's a problem with the name of your `getB_runtime_factor()` method. It should be called something like: `initializeB_runtime_factor()`. Because this doesn't return anything. And you won't need it to return the factor.
Because your map is accessible in your `B_CALC_click()` method. To access a Map value using a key, you can use the `get()` method. Also, you can check if the map contains the factor using the `containsKey()` method. Here's the code for your case:

```
public void initializeB_runtime_factor() {
    B_runtime_factor_Map = new Map <Double, Double>();
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(0, 1.000);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(1, 0.800);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(2, 0.700);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(3, 0.600);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(4, 0.500);
    B_runtime_factor_Map.put(5, 0.400);
    ......
}

public PageReference B_CALC_click() {
    B_runtime = Date.Today().daysBetween(B_Birthdate) / 365;
    initializeB_runtime_factor();
    if(B_runtime_factor_Map.containsKey(B_runtime)){
        B_Result = B_Value_per_Month * 12 * B_runtime_factor_Map.get(B_runtime);       
        return new PageReference('/apex/Parameter_info');
    }else{
        //execute what you want when the key is not in the map
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: If I save the code I get the message from the developer console "Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement", could you help?

Comment: I updated my answer. You needed to add a `return null` at the end of the `B_CALC_click()` method. Because you're supposed to return a `PageReference`.